# Ruby Webdrivers Gem Cannot Reach Site

Tags: ruby, webdriver, watir

I am using the webdrivers gem for Ruby (not selenium webdriver) https://rubygems.org/gems/webdrivers/versions/3.2.0

I can get the gem to update chrome fine, it places it in webdrivers new directory and sees the version of the chrome driver. I only used the `update` and `latest` methods on Webdrivers::Chromedriver. My issue is when trying to get the Webdrivers::Geckodriver installed (firefox). I get the error message: `Cannot reach site`. The documentation is a little lacking, does anyone know the proper setup for firefox? or why i get this error?

Answer (score 0):

First, update to the latest version, there are a couple minor bugs that were fixed since your version.

You should only be seeing that error if the gem can't access the github site where mozilla stores its release binaries. So very likely a temporary issue.

If it isn't already working again, set `Webdrivers.logger.level = :debug` to get more info about what is happening, and we can debug it.

Comment: Updated to latest version and added debugging, still get about the same: `2018-11-06 09:58:24 DEBUG Webdrivers Site Not Available: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases`

Comment: Does your computer have internet access

Comment: yes, it can reach the google driver and the ie driver.

Comment: what version of Ruby?